# How to use R to create a new daframe from the proportion of information found in another?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dplyr

In R and with tidyverse I have a dataframe called “total” with these columns:

"IdPedido", "ProtocoloPedido", "OrgaoSuperiorAssociadoaoDestinatario", "OrgaoDestinatario", "Situacao", "DataRegistro", "ResumoSolicitacao", "DetalhamentoSolicitacao", "PrazoAtendimento", "FoiProrrogado", "FoiReencaminhado", "FormaResposta", "OrigemSolicitacao", "IdSolicitante", "CategoriaPedido", "SubCategoriaPedido", "NumeroPerguntas", "DataResposta", "Resposta", "TipoResposta", "ClassificacaoTipoResposta" and "IdPedido_ano"

Here is a summary:

```
dput(total[1:2, ])
structure(list(IdPedido = c("345365", "345366"), ProtocoloPedido = c("99901000001201633", 
"99902000001201623"), OrgaoSuperiorAssociadoaoDestinatario = c(NA, 
NA), OrgaoDestinatario = c("BB – Banco do Brasil S.A.", "CEF – Caixa Econômica Federal"
), Situacao = c("Respondido", "Respondido"), DataRegistro = structure(c(1451640253, 
1451648416), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    ResumoSolicitacao = c("consultar meu cpf . no spc e serasa", 
    "Esclarecimentos sobre seguro de risco de incêndio"), DetalhamentoSolicitacao = c("Consulta do cpf no serasa e spc", 
    "Sou conselheiro de um Condomínio e depois da publicação da NORMA ABNT 16.280 que começou a valer a partir de 18/04/2014 tenho as seguintes dúvidas com relação a instalação de ares condicionados nas unidades condominiais.  Pergunto: quem colocou os ares condicionados antes da publicação da Norma da ABNT esses condôminos têm que apresentar ao síndico a ART da instalação ou não? A Lei retroage nestes casos?  Recentemente um condômino contratou um engenheiro civil para fazer algumas obras no seu apto e instalou os ares condicionados e o engenheiro forneceu a ART.Pergunto: Pode um engenheiro civil dar ART para instalação de ar condicionado? Não é atribuição específica de um engenheiro eletricista?  Se houver um incêndio em sua unidade o seguro pode exigir a ART de um engenheiro eletricista ou não? Vai ter problemas com o seguro caso haja um incêndio nesta unidade habitacional?  Cito como exemplo vários incêndios que ocorreram no passado (Edifício Joelma ) cuja causa foi por causa da instalação elétrica e pegou fogo nos ares condicionados, alguns aptos em Copacabana também.  Fico no aguardo dos esclarecimentos necessários acerca das exigências e implicações das Seguradoras em caso de ocorrer um incêndio em nosso Condomínio por causa da instalação de ares condicionados.  Atenciosamente,  Luciano Miniero"
    ), PrazoAtendimento = structure(c(1453766399, 1453766399), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), FoiProrrogado = c("NÃO", "NÃO"
    ), FoiReencaminhado = c("NÃO", "NÃO"), FormaResposta = c("Pelo sistema (com avisos por email)", 
    "Pelo sistema (com avisos por email)"), OrigemSolicitacao = c("Internet", 
    "Internet"), IdSolicitante = c("604629", "537117"), CategoriaPedido = c("Economia e Finanças", 
    "Economia e Finanças"), SubCategoriaPedido = c("Economia", 
    "Economia"), NumeroPerguntas = c("1", "1"), DataResposta = structure(c(1453721439, 
    1452011569), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Resposta = c("Prezado(a) Sr(a). Gisela,  Encaminhamos, em anexo, resposta ao seu pedido de informação.  Atenciosamente,  Serviço de Informação ao Cidadão do Banco do Brasil – SICBB  Recurso  Conforme a Lei 12527/11 em seu artigo Art. 15, no caso de indeferimento de acesso a informações ou às razões da negativa do acesso, poderá o interessado interpor recurso contra a decisão no prazo de 10 (dez) dias a contar da sua ciência.  Parágrafo único. O recurso será dirigido à autoridade hierarquicamente superior à que exarou a decisão impugnada, que deverá se manifestar no prazo de 5 (cinco) dias.", 
    "Prezado (a) Senhor (a),     1. Em atenção a sua solicitação, registrada através do E-SIC, site CGU, informamos que não foi possível compreender o seu pedido.     2. Caso seja pertinente à CAIXA, orientamos gerar novo pedido detalhando a sua solicitação.     3. Informamos que a CAIXA mantém SAC para informações, reclamações, cancelamentos, sugestões, serviços e elogios, com atendimento 24 horas por dia 07 dias por semana, pelo DDG 0800 726 0101 e para reclamações não solucionadas no SAC ou denúncias, a CAIXA mantém canal de Ouvidoria com atendimento de segunda a sexta-feira, das 08 às 18 horas, pelo DDG 0800 725 7474.    4. A CAIXA coloca-se à disposição através de seus canais de atendimento.       Atenciosamente,    CAIXA – Serviço de Informações ao Cidadão"
    ), TipoResposta = c("Acesso Concedido", "Acesso Negado"), 
    ClassificacaoTipoResposta = c("Resposta solicitada inserida no e-SIC", 
    "Pedido incompreensível"), IdPedido_ano = c("345365_2016", 
    "345366_2016")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It is a dataframe on requests for access to information in Brazil. The “OrgaoDestinatario” column has the name of the institutions that received the requests. And the column "TipoResposta" which was the type of response to the request

I counted the two columns

```
total %>%  count(OrgaoDestinatario, sort = TRUE)
A tibble: 295 x 2
   OrgaoDestinatario                                              n
   <chr>                                                      <int>
 1 ME - Ministério da Economia                                21000
 2 CEF – Caixa Econômica Federal                               7212
 3 MS – Ministério da Saúde                                    6913
 4 ANEEL – Agência Nacional de Energia Elétrica                6596
 5 INSS – Instituto Nacional do Seguro Social                  5674
 6 BACEN – Banco Central do Brasil                             4281
 7 MAPA – Ministério da Agricultura, Pecuária e Abastecimento  3978
 8 MEC – Ministério da Educação                                3632
 9 ANVISA – Agência Nacional de Vigilância Sanitária           3494
10 MDR - Ministério do Desenvolvimento Regional                3167
# … with 285 more rows

total %>%  count(TipoResposta, sort = TRUE)
 A tibble: 21 x 2
   TipoResposta                                                  n
   <chr>                                                     <int>
 1 Acesso Concedido                                         129330
 2 Não se trata de solicitação de informação                 12128
 3 Acesso Negado                                             10241
 4 Acesso Parcialmente Concedido                              8832
 5 Órgão não tem competência para responder sobre o assunto   6523
 6 Informação Inexistente                                     5600
 7 Pergunta Duplicada/Repetida                                3786
 8 Encaminhado para o e-Ouv                                    660
 9 Resposta solicitada inserida no e-SIC                        15
10 Informações enviadas por e-mail                              13
# … with 11 more rows
```

And also sub-counts within an “TipoResposta” of an entity. Example:

```
ECO <- total %>%
  filter(OrgaoDestinatario == "ME - Ministério da Economia")

ECO %>%  count(TipoResposta, sort = TRUE)
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  TipoResposta                                                 n
  <chr>                                                    <int>
1 Acesso Concedido                                         12120
2 Não se trata de solicitação de informação                 4679
3 Acesso Negado                                             1824
4 Órgão não tem competência para responder sobre o assunto   707
5 Informação Inexistente                                     560
6 Acesso Parcialmente Concedido                              530
7 Pergunta Duplicada/Repetida                                485
8 Encaminhado para o e-Ouv                                    94
9 NA                                                           1
```

I want to create a new dataframe in which there is a column called “list_of_entities” and each line of it contains “OrgaoDestinatario” information, without repeating it (in this case 295 lines). Example:

```
list_of_entities
ME - Ministério da Economia
CEF – Caixa Econômica Federal
MS – Ministério da Saúde
ANEEL – Agência Nacional de Energia Elétrica
INSS – Instituto Nacional do Seguro Social
BACEN – Banco Central do Brasil
MAPA – Ministério da Agricultura, Pecuária e Abastecimento
…
```

And the other columns with the names found in "TipoResposta": “Acesso Concedido”, “ Não se trata de solicitação de informação”, “Acesso Negado”…

But the rows in each of these columns will have the result of math account, a number, relative to the value of "list_of_entities": the sum of the “TipoResposta” category of the respective entity divided by the total requests of that entity, multiplied by 100
Example:

“ME - Ministério da Economia” had 21,000 requests and in the item “Acesso Concedido” there were 12,120 cases. So it's 12,120 / 21,000 * 100 = 57.71
So in the new dataframe in the line “ME - Ministério da Economia” and in the column “Acesso Concedido” there would be the value 57.71

Continuing, in the item “Não se trata de solicitação de informação” there were 4,679, so the account would be 4,679 / 21,000 * 100 = 22.28
Then, in the new dataframe in the line “ME - Ministério da Economia” and in the column “Não se trata de solicitação de informação” the value would be 22.28
And so on, in all columns and then in all other entities and their columns

Please, does anyone know how I could do this with R?

Comment: I can't check since you only provided 2 rows of your data, but does this do what you want? ```total %>% 
  count(OrgaoDestinatario, TipoResposta) %>% # add counts
  group_by(OrgaoDestinatario) %>% 
  mutate(fraction = n / sum(n)) %>%  # turn counts into fractions
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = TipoResposta, values_from = fraction) # turn rows into columns```

Comment: Thank you very much @Bas I just needed to install tidyverse on devtools for pivot_wider to work. But some "TipoResposta" columns are wrong. Looks like the script collected information from another column

Comment: @Bas I put the total.csv file here if you want to test: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1unCbxWBrI7NzWqgU365zLbFc6yiq0eKO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm pretty sure pivot_wider is in the newest version of the tidyverse on CRAN as well. Your csv is a little bit weird in the sense that there are quoted strings in the DetalhamentoSolicitacao column which also contain quotes. Therefore some columns get shifted, and I get dates in the 'TipoReposta' column. I think that is an issue with your dataset that needs cleaning.